# Timeline of "Quick opinions" in math journal refereeing

Tags: publications, mathematics, peer-review, journals, editors

Some years ago a fair number of mathematics journals started to ask for one or more "quick opinions" by experts on a received manuscript before sending it out for peer-review (with the obvious goal of avoiding the hassle of peer-review for papers that clearly don't make the cut). In your experience, how long does it take on average to receive a quick opinion? Or, phrased differently, how long after submission can you usually deduce that your manuscript has survived quick opinions and is sent out for peer-review? This question is only within the scope of mathematics.

Comment: The answer is clearly journal dependent. I would guess that when the web submission portal says the status is "under review" that the paper has survived that cut.

Comment: The two quick rejections I've gotten took 1 month and slightly under 2 months, respectively.  Small sample though.  @EthanBolker, for both of these journals submission was by email, no web portals in sight.

Comment: In a third instance, the editor forwarded me a comment from a quick-opinionated expert after 2 months and a week.

Answer (score 2):

I've been asked for "quick opinions" from a variety of good-to-best journals, and I try to meet the obvious goal of "quick...", if nothing else.

In some cases, I've easily seen the need for various sorts of revision, and immediately recommended that, with a promise that I'd look at it again later when it was more readable.

In some cases, I do also easily confess that, while I myself may not see the point or interest of a project, perhaps there is one... and, if nothing else, the author(s) perhaps should revise to make that clearer (if possible).

Anyway, usually I succeed in giving "quick responses" in a week or less, as one data point.